# Upload 3D model in to unity app which is stored in to the DB

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new for unity.. In my project I have a function that indicate Interior designing using Augment reality.. The thing is the designer can be able to upload their designed interior design in to our app, for this I need some help, When I refer the internet I got the information about 'online Directory' (For store the asset in to that, then he can upload that), I don't know whether it will be useful or not, Can any one please suggest a solution for this scenario?

Comment: What are you asking? If users should be able to upload something? Please consider re-writing this and leave out parts that are not related to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is important to know that the user can not send a 3D model (.FBX) to the app. You can only use existing models within Unity 3D.

If you want the user to download new 3D models, you can use [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html).

If you want the user to create a decoration and share it with friends, you should create a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) / [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) with all objects and positions and save it to your database. When another user requests this file, it will be downloaded and the objects will be dynamically created in a scene for the user to admire all 3D objects.